# Ubuntu Installation Wiped Whole Drive

Tags: partitioning

An error occurred in the partitioning stage of an Ubuntu 10.10 installation on my computer that caused me to restart and now all of my other partitions are gone.

Is there a way to recover these files?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/3883/83046

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that your partition table was corrupted but your partitions are still there.

There is a tool available in the Ubuntu LiveCD called gpart that can recover your partition table.

http://www.brzitwa.de/mb/gpart/index.html

Load the Live CD, install it (`sudo apt-get install gpart`) and then run `gpart`.

Comment: This is probably your best shot at recovery.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation of how to do this at the Ubuntu wiki:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost Partition

It explains how to use the gpart tool, as well as a utility called testdisk.

There's a great article on the same subject, including data recovery, at UbuntuGeek:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/